# Stop the back history, just close popup

Tags: jquery-mobile, back, browser-history, jquery-mobile-popup

When I click the back button on the browser, my popup closes but the listener events brought me back to the previous page, I want in my function an element that closes the popup without me go back. While keeping the history listener to other pages (don't stop in the whole of the application)

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#member", function (){
   $(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
      var direction = data.state.direction;
      if (direction == 'back') {
        $("#mypopup").popup("close");
      }
   });
});
```

I try with

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
   $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
});
```

But don't working

Comment: You want to close panel or popup?

Comment: Sorry a popup, but i think for panel the method is similary ?

Comment: It's not the same. Playing with JQM history isn't easy. Anyway, you don't need to wrap code in `pageshow`, just remove it. Add `data-history="true"` to popup div.

Comment: data-history="true" work very well, but don't work on the popup iframe and how proceed for the panel ?